# wrpcap not creating pcap file, when running in separate thread

Tags: python, multithreading, scapy, python-2.5

I'm trying to capture network traffic using scapy , by running sniff in a thread rather than running it in the main thread itself. So as to avoid blocking of the app . But the problem that i'm facing is that that the wrpcap is not creating a file, if it does it creates a 0 Kb file.

The other reason why i'm using a separate thread is, because i want to be able to close the thread when the user wishes to end the capture.

```
from scapy.all import *
from time import gmtime , strftime
import threading
import time

def bomber(stop_event):
    data=[]
    pkts=[]
    while not stop_event.isSet() :
        pkt100=sniff(count=100)
        data.append(pkt100)

    for pkt in data:
        for x in range(100):
            pkts.append(pkt[x])
    pktsRoll=PacketList(pkts)

    savename="F:\\%s.pcap" % strftime("%Y-%m-%d,%H:%M", gmtime())
    wrpcap(savename,pktsRoll)
    print " its done "


def main():
    stop_event = threading.Event()
    c_thread = threading.Thread(target=bomber, args=(stop_event,))
    c_thread.start()
    time.sleep(20)
    stop_event.set()
```

This is the code that i'm trying out . I'm using Python 2.5

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does "its done" print?

Comment: yes it does but ,it prints after some time. But it does not put anything in the file.

Comment: @RyPeck : yes it does , but it does after some time . So what i did is decrease the number of packet's it captures in one loop cycle and evidently its working fine.

Comment: So the problem seems to be that you didn't have enough packets on the network going around to ever get to the point where you write the PCAP file?

Comment: @RyPeck : No that's not the problem , i put a video download simultaneously to generate traffic. What i think the problem is , is that the thread shuts down before it gets to the part where it writes into the file.